# how to export images using abbyfine reader?

Tags: pdf, epub, ebook-management

Presently, I using the abbyfine reader for text extraction. Is there a way to export the images from abbyfine reader software? Please advise.

Comment: I have answered to you under the assumption that you want to extract the images from epub files, but I'm not sure if I have interpreted it correctly. Could you please edit your question to make it a little clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can export images in Abby Finereader when you convert PDF to HTML.

First abby will automatically determine images if not zone the image area manually.

Second in options menu (Top right) select save -> HTML -> select Keep Pictures, so when you save as html you will get all the images in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you are trying to extract images from an `.epub` file.

If it is the case, it is very simple and you don't need any particular software to do so. Ebooks in `.epub` format are basically just renamed `.zip` files, so you can extract or open them with whichever is your compressed file manager; the pictures are usually kept in the root folder or in the `OEBPS` or `OEBPS/images` folders.